# Subproccesses remain alive after Racket program halts

Tags: shell, process, racket, zombie-process

I have the following program that spins up 100 different processes (and yes, I know I should be closing the ports, I'm just not doing it in this example):

```
#lang racket ; evil.rkt

(require compiler/find-exe)

(for ([i (in-range 100)])
  (process* (find-exe) "-e" "(let loop () (loop))"))
```

As expected, when I run this program, and run `ps -fe | grep 'racket'` to get a list of all of the processes running racket, I see something like:

```
....
73187 ??         0:00.47 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
73188 ??         0:00.44 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
73189 ??         0:00.45 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
73190 ??         0:00.45 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
73191 ??         0:00.43 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
73192 ??         0:00.41 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
73193 ??         0:00.39 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
73194 ??         0:00.35 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
73195 ??         0:00.34 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
73196 ??         0:00.34 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
73197 ??         0:00.29 /Users/leif/racket/racket/bin/racket -e (let loop () (loop))
....
```

The problem is that even after the program terminates, these processes are still running.

If I run it in the shell, and press Ctr+C to terminate the program, most of the processes stop. However, occasionally one or two of them will keep running.

When I switch to using [`process`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html?q=process#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsystem..rkt%29._process%29%29) rather than [`process*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html?q=process#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsystem..rkt%29._process%2A%29%29) this problem goes away. Is there anything I can do to make sure that my subprocesses stop when I terminate the program?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that, by default, subprocesses spawned by Racket are not shut down by the custodian when your program terminates.

The reason you don't have this problem with `process` is because the `process` function starts up a shell (such as `/bin/sh`) and runs your command in that. That shell is taking care of the subprocesses. On the other hand, `process*` runs your subprocess directly, and thus Racket is responsible for it, or it will become a zombie process.

The reason this is much less of a problem when you are running this in a shell (as opposed to DrRacket), is because your shell likely has your process, and all of its subprocesses, in its own process group. Thus, when a Ctr+C is pressed, the shell sends a SIGINT to all of the processes in the process group, which include all of your process's subprocesses. Occasionally, unfortunately, there are processes that are too new to be added to the group (or they are created moments after the SIGINT is sent, I'm not entirely sure of the mechanics here), and thus they are left alive.

All of this can be worked around by setting the [`current-subprocess-custodian-mode`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html?q=current-subprocess-custodian-mode#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-subprocess-custodian-mode%29%29) parameter to `'kill` (or `'interrupt`), so that a Racket [custodian](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html?q=custodian#%28tech._custodian%29) will terminate your process before it terminates. Modifying your code would thus look like:

```
#lang racket

(require compiler/find-exe)

(parameterize ([current-subprocess-custodian-mode 'kill])
  (for ([i (in-range 100)])
    (process* (find-exe) "-e" "(let loop () (loop))")) )
```

(Note that this still does rely on Racket to shut down your subprocesses. If you use a library like `ffi/unsafe` and cause Racket to segfault, the subprocesses will still be running.)

As an addendum, note that the process will only die once your program ends (or when the current custodian shuts things down, such as in a sandbox), if you want to stop the subprocess before it you'll have to send it a interrupt/kill signal yourself, which you can do with the callback that the `process*` function returns.